# setState() not taking further argument (e) for changing value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

**I want to append the pervious value of state with the current value of the input box** 
but when i use **setState** function its somehow not allowing to pass event as argument.

**Problem**:
setState(prev,props,**e**) 
The 3rd argument (e) is not getting detected by **setState** function.

e.target.value is coming undefined

This is my code :

```
import React , {Component} from 'react'
class Todo extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={toDo:[],currentInput:"name"}
        // bind the events
        this.addItem=this.addItem.bind(this)
        this.changeList=this.changeList.bind(this)


    }

    addItem(e){
        // prevent default 
        e.preventDefault();

        // this part is left
    }
    changeList(e){


        this.setState(function (prev,props,e){
            console.log(prev.currentInput)
            return {currentInput:prev.currentInput+e.target.value} // this part is causing problem
        })
    }


    render(){
        return(
            <div className="App">
               <h1>Add your tasks</h1> 
            <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.currentInput} onChange={this.changeList} ></input>
                <input type="submit"></input>

            </form>
                <div className="List">
                    <h3>Remaining items:-</h3>
                    <ul>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }


}

export default Todo
```

Comment: I know the simple way of getting the value but i want to understand whats going wrong with this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how `setState` works, you can't pass additional arguments, if you pass a function, React will invoke it passing in the current `state` and the `props` as arguments

Worth mentioning that if you use a functional update you have to capture the input value before you call `setState` or call `event.persist()` as React will clear the event after the handler has been invoked setting `event.target` to `null`

[Event polling](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling)

Example

```js
changeList(e){
  const { value } = e.target
  // or call e.persist() and use e.target.value inside the function

  // now it's safe to use a functional update
  this.setState(prevState => ({ 
    currentInput: prevState.currentInput + value 
  }))
}
```

You also don't want to append to the previous input state as `e.target.value` contains the full input value so you can just pass an object into `setState`

```js
changeList(e){
  this.setState({ currentInput: e.target.value })
}
```

Comment: yeah i understand your solution but i wasnt knowing much about the setState and want to try that way . Just a begineer thnks again,

Answer (score 0):

you don't actually need to do `prev.currentInput+e.target.value` as e.target.value will be the current input value ... if you type `alpha` in input it will actually evaluate to `namenamealpha` whereas my guess is you are expecting `namealpha`

but if you still wanna make it work here is how you should do it

```js
import React , {Component} from 'react'
class Todo extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={toDo:[],currentInput:"name"}
    }

    addItem = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    changeList = (e) => {
      const newValue = e.target.value;
      this.setState((state) => {
        console.log({state, newValue})
        return({
          currentInput: state.currentInput + newValue
        })
      });
    }


    render(){
        return(
            <div className="App">
               <h1>Add your tasks</h1> 
            <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.currentInput} onChange={this.changeList} ></input>
                <input type="submit"></input>

            </form>
                <div className="List">
                    <h3>Remaining items:-</h3>
                    <ul>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }


}

export default Todo
```

Alternatively and ideally you can also use hooks like this

```js
import React , { useState }from 'react'
const Todo = () => {
    const [currentInput, setCurrentInput] = useState('name');

        return(
            <div className="App">
               <h1>Add your tasks</h1> 
            <form onSubmit={() => console.log('submit')}>
                <input type="text" value={currentInput} onChange={(e) => setCurrentInput(e.target.value)} ></input>
                <input type="submit"></input>

            </form>
                <div className="List">
                    <h3>Remaining items:-</h3>
                    <ul>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
}

export default Todo
```